# Project ERROR: This mkspec requires Xcode 4.3 or later

Tags: ios, qt, qmake, qt5.9

**Scenario:**
I have updated to *Qt 5.9.6* and I have *Xcode 10.0* running on *High Sierra*.

I have a *Qt App* that builds for *OSX* and *iOS*. And it builds and runs all well with *Qt 5.9.4*.

Now, I want to update to 5.9.6 for a reason. When I try to build for iOS using *Qt 5.9.6*, I get the following error

> Project ERROR: This mkspec requires Xcode 4.3 or later

**Question:**
Is there a way to get around this issue?

**Note** that the OSX build using *Qt 5.9.6* just works fine. I have `QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` set to `10.0` for *iOS* case

**PS:**
I also deleted the `.qmake.stash` and the `.pro.user` file from the root directory and restarted QtCreator to try build from a a fresh start. But still get the same issue!

Comment: maybe the problem is that "4.3" > "10.0". Maby the build-scripts just can not compare version numbers properly.

Comment: I have same problem on Mojave. Maybe it will be fixed in Qt 5.9.7 https://forum.qt.io/topic/95659/project-error-this-mkspec-requires-xcode-4-3-or-later/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in Qt, use Qt 5.9.7 where this bug is fixed.